# formataçao para telas diferentes, algumas nao funcionam

Tags: css

queria saber se as `media queries` tem ordem de maior para menos ou vise versa, porque eu formato em um tamanho especifico funciona certinho, ai vou formata para outra tela a anterior deixa de funciona vise e versa, queria saber se tem uma ordem

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss meu problema é outro, minhas queries estão totalmente diferente da pergunta `duplicada` eu so especifico `max-width` nao `min-width`

Comment: Bruno edite sua pergunta e coloca seu CSS completo, ai que fica mais para te dar uma resposta mais precisa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As medias *querys* funcionam em ordem de processamento igual os códigos css normais.

Imagine que você tem um `b{ text-align:center }` na linha 1 e outro `b{text-align:left}` na linha 20. O que ira valer é o da linha 20 pois em ordem de processamento ela vem depois e **sobrescreve a anterior**. Tenha isto em mente.

Eu geralmente começo o responsivo com a maior tela e vou colocando as regras das telas menores depois para sobrescrever as maiores.

entendendo isto, tem também o recurso de você deixar as regras visíveis ou não para determinado tamanho, como:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {  a {color: yellow;} }
```

esta regra só deixara visível para resolução menores que 768px. Assim como você pode utilizar `max-width` ou ambas juntas.

Tendo essas regras em vista é possível você criar as suas *midias querys* de varias formas possíveis.

você também pode utilizar essa media *query* na chamada do doc

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)">
```

Comment: tem alguma diferença entre `@media (max-width:)`, `@media screen and (max-width:)`, `@media screen only (max-width:)` ?

Comment: O `media (max-width)` é geral , 
O **screen** é utilizado para monitores ou dispositivos com telas coloridas em geral, uma outra possibilidade é o **Print** que é apenas para impressão. E não são renderizados na tela.
O only nunca utilizei pra ser sincero.
Achei este link que vai ser perfeito para você: https://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-css-media-queries/27085